# Python os.system: Order of commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, git-bash, python-os

Why does calling the file `a.py` with content

```
import os
print('Hi')
os.system('cat a.py')
```

yield the following output and how can I get them to print in the correct order?

```
$ python a.py
import os
print('Hi')
os.system('cat a.py')
Hi
```

You see that the `cat` command prints to stdout before `print` does. Happens when running Python 3.6 in GitBash on Windows 10. Does **not** happen with Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 17.10.

---

*Note:* I'm aware that I can get around printing the content of a file with something like `file.readlines()` easily. This is just a simple example. However, when running something more complex, it can become important to understand *why* this happens and how to get around it

Comment: Why are you not using `subprocess.Popen` ? `os.system` shouldn't be used. The behaviour of `subprocess.Popen` is guaranteed to be same in all OS

Comment: @user1767754: The subprocess's behavior isn't what's different, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Output is buffered. You have to flush this buffer:

```
import os
import sys
print('Hi')
sys.stdout.flush()
os.system('cat a.py')
```

Comment: Couldn't you call `python -u` for unbuffered as well?

Comment: Can you also explain why it works on Ubuntu without flushing?

Comment: Normally, with stdout connected to a terminal, output would be line-buffered (and thus the line terminator would cause the `Hi` output to be automatically flushed), but Git Bash may change things.

Comment: Ok, could have guessed that it's got something to do with GitBash. That's what I get for using Windows! :D

Answer (score 0):

That is a cleaner way of doing it.

```
from subprocess import check_output  
print check_output(['cat', 'a.py'])
```

Comment: That's not going to change anything.

Comment: So you are saying, that this will yield the same result?

Comment: Unless it does something with the Python script's output buffering for some reason, it's going to yield the same result as the `os.system` code.